# Atualizando apenas uma tr com ajax com dados retornadados do mysql

Tags: javascript, ajax

Este é o código em HTML supondo que já foi processado pelo PHP.

```
<table width="900" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>nome</td>
    <td>endereço</td>
    <td>tel</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Adriano</td>
    <td>Rua Rio de Janeiro</td>
    <td>35744455</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <td><label for="nome"></label>
      <input name="nome" type="text" id="nome" value="Adriano"></td>
    <td><input name="endereco" type="text" id="endereco" value="Rua Rio de Janeiro"></td>
    <td><input name="tel" type="text" id="tel" value="35744455"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit"></td>
    </form>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Irma</td>
    <td>Rua Mato Gross</td>
    <td>35744455</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <form name="form2" method="post" action="">
    <td><input name="nome" type="text" id="nome" value="Irma">
    </td>
    <td><input name="endereco" type="text" id="endereco" value="Rua Mato Gross"></td>
    <td><input name="tel" type="text" id="tel" value="35744455"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit"></td>
  </form>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Cristiane</td>
    <td>Rua São Paulo</td>
    <td>35744455</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <form name="form3" method="post" action="">
    <td><input name="nome" type="text" id="nome" value="Cristiane">
    </td>
    <td><input name="endereco" type="text" id="endereco" value="Rua São Paulo"></td>
    <td><input name="tel" type="text" id="tel" value="35744455"></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit"></td>
    </form>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Existe uma `<tr>` com os dados retornados do banco de dados e logo abaixo outra `<tr>` com campos de um formulário preenchidos com os mesmos valores já exibidos aguardando serem atualizados pelo usuário.

O programa vai alterar os dados, retornar e atualizar apenas a `<tr>` onde os dados são mostrados sem dar um *refresh* na pagina.

Comment: Uma pergunta, vc tem conhecimento de javascript? E jQuery?

Comment: Recomendo você estudar ajax antes de perguntar novamente, faça exemplos simples, depois de aprender, formule uma possível solução, e aí sim, poste dúvidas aqui.

Comment: A solução que eu quero é para este livro Caixa que esta neste link
http://paulocollares.com.br/livro_caixa_demo/login.php o autor disponibilizou o código e é possível ver como funciona a aplicação,  se acessar o site dele você vai poder ver o que eu quero fazer. 

Ao acessar a aplicação já cai no movimento do mês, ai se você for querer editar um movimento, ele abre uma TR que esta oculta com um formulário dentro, quando você altera, ele da um refresh na pagina, e processa a pagina novamente. 

Queria que quando fosse editado, o processo acontecesse somente onde foi editado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer utilizando o callback de success da sua requisiçao ajax:

```
$(document).on('click', '#button', function() {
    // armazena o botão do formulário que está requisitando o ajax
    var caller = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: caller.parents('form').serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            // console.debug(data);
            // pega a <tr> do botão clicado e faz alguma coisa
            caller.parents('tr').doSomething();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Olá Victor, obrigado por me responder, mas não consegui entender o código, você conhece algum exemplo para o código passado, o que eu quero resolver esta neste link paulocollares.com.br/livro_caixa_demo/login.php o autor disponibilizou o código e é possível ver como funcionam, se acessar o site dele você vai poder ver o que eu quero fazer. Ao acessar a aplicação já cai no movimento do mês, ai se você for querer editar um movimento, ele abre uma TR que esta oculta com um formulário dentro, quando você altera, ele da um refresh na pagina. quero que atualize sem refresh.